# Scroll Box Responsive issue, CSS-Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, scroll, responsive-design

Wondering if someone can help me out a bit.
I have a scrolling text box on a page in Wordpress.
The site is responsive. The box is exactly the way I need it except it doesn't re size down with the rest of the content on the page.

Does it have to do with the fact its a fixed width? If so how do I change it so it shrinks down?
Thanks

```
<div style="border: 4px solid #ffff00; overflow: auto; height: 150px; width: 640px; color: white; background-color: #32cd32;">
<div style="text-align: left;">
<h1>Add Text</h1>
```

Add Text

```
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving dimensions of that `<div>` in `%` instead of `px`.

Elements with dimensions in `px`are of fixed size hence not responsive.

Read more about it [here](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to give the `height` and `width` some percentage.

Below is the demo with some sample content and `overflow:auto`

```
#box{
    position:absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:auto;
    border: solid red 2px;
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nyb4T/)